# Definition of voltage for motional EMF

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

In the schoolbook physics example of a generator, the wire loop rotating in a constant (both in space and time) magnetic field, we can measure a non-zero voltage between the loop's two terminals due to the EMF. Since the magnetic field is constant in time, by the Maxwell-Faraday equation the rotation of $E$ vanishes:

$$ \mathrm{rot}(E) = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t} = 0$$

If I then plug in the standard (?) definition for voltage/potential difference between the two terminals I find

$$
\begin{align}
U_{\partial S} &= -\int_{\partial S} E \cdot \mathrm{d}(\partial S) \\
&= - \int_S \mathrm{rot}(E)\cdot\mathrm{d}S \\
&= \int_S \frac{\partial B}{\partial t}\cdot\mathrm{d}S \\
& = \int_S 0 \cdot \mathrm{d}S \\
& = 0
\end{align}
$$

(the loop $\partial S$ encloses the surface $S$)

However, as mentioned above, a volt-meter will definitely measure a voltage across the two terminals.

Is the definition of voltage I used above somehow not adequate in this setting?

Comment: Interpret ${\partial\over\partial t}\int_S \vec B\cdot d\vec S$ as the time rate of change of magnetic flux, then clearly the quantity only vanishes for a static loop.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus It is true that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_S\vec B\cdot d\vec S$ is not always zero, but it is also not equal to $\oint_{\partial S}\vec E\cdot d\ell$ if $\vec B$ is static. One needs to be careful when defining the path of integration and relating the integral to a voltage.

Comment: How is my suggestion not the same as Lenz's law?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus See my answer for the subtleties. Also, I should have said "if the loop is moving" instead of "if $\vec B$ is static" in my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

You can only apply Stokes' theorem on a closed loop. If you are integrating $\vec E$ along a closed loop in static $\vec B$, according to the Maxwell-Faraday equation the answer is always zero, regardless of motional emf (e.g. consider a simple circuit with a battery). If you are integrating $\vec E$ between two terminals, you cannot directly apply Stokes' theorem and conclude the voltage is zero.

The force per unit charge along a piece of wire (directed along unit vector $\hat \ell$) is
$$\vec f \cdot \hat \ell = (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)\cdot \hat \ell$$
where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the piece of wire. If either the current in the wire is zero (e.g. because it doesn't form a closed loop, or it is connected to a high-impedance load like a voltmeter), or if the resistance of the wire can be neglected, then $\vec f \cdot \hat \ell=0$, for the same reason we assume $\vec E = 0$ in near-ideal conductors in a stationary circuit.

The voltage between the two ends $A$ and $B$ of the wire is then
$$U_{BA} = -\int\limits_A^B \vec E\cdot \hat \ell d\ell = \int\limits_A^B \left(\vec v\times\vec B\right)\cdot \hat \ell d\ell.$$

---

There is another way to express the voltage across an open wire that is especially useful if the wire *almost* forms a closed loop, with its terminals separated by a small distance. Let $C_1$ be the open curve from $A$ to $B$ along the wire, and $C_2$ an "imaginary" curve from $B$ to $A$ that completes the loop. [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Faraday%27s_law) (or the "flux rule") says
$$\mathcal E=\oint\limits_{C_1 + C_2} (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B) \cdot d\vec\ell=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$$
where $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux through $C_1 + C_2$. The integral along $C_1$ is zero, as discussed above. Moreover, since $\oint_{C_1 + C_2}\vec E\cdot d\vec\ell = 0$ in a static magnetic field, we can write $\int_{C_1}\vec E\cdot d\vec\ell = -\int_{C_2}\vec E\cdot d\vec\ell$. We end up with
$$U_{BA} = -\int\limits_{C_1} \vec E\cdot d\vec\ell = \int\limits_{C_2} \vec E\cdot d\vec\ell = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt} -\int\limits_{C_2} \left(\vec v\times\vec B\right)\cdot d\vec\ell.$$
If $C_2$ is sufficiently short or is not moving very fast, the last integral can be neglected, so we have the familiar result in terms of rate of change of flux.

Comment: OK. But still $U$ defined above (which $= 0$) seems - in my understanding - to contradict any EMF $ \ne 0$.

Comment: @DamianBirchler See my updated answer.

Comment: @Puk Ok I see, my comment came out stupid as it did because I jumped the gun with Stoke's law...

Comment: Did you mean "if the resistance of the wire can be neglected, then $\boldsymbol{E}\cdot\boldsymbol{l}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{0}$" above?

Comment: @DamianBirchler No, I did mean $\vec f \cdot \hat \ell = 0$. We are using the fact that it doesn't take much force to move charge around and produce a sizable current in a good conductor. This reduces to $\vec E \cdot \hat \ell = 0$ for a stationary wire.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) one assumes a fixed loop and a magnetic field that changes its orientation and in this case you would get what you expected, namely that $\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{B}}{\mathrm{dt}}\neq0$.

Short explanation:
Change to the reference frame in which the loop is at rest and you have reconstructed the situation from above. Now the magnetic field changes in time and the voltage drop occurs directly.

Longer explanation

Let us assume that the magnetic field in this case remains constant and is oriented about the z-axis:
$$
\mathbf{B}=\left(\begin{array}\\0\\0\\B\end{array}\right)
$$
Furthermore it is assumed that the loop changes its orientation as in your question stated.
For the sake of simplicity let us assume a single circular loop of radius $R$ rotating at fixed frequency $\omega>0$ around the x-axis. The case $\omega=0$ won't lead to unexpected results because then everything (magentic field, orientation of the loop, etc.) is static and so no voltage builds up in acccordance to your explanation.

The loop is best described in polar coordinates:
At time $t=0$:
$$
\mathbf{l}_{RF:B}(R,\phi,t=0)= R \left(\begin{array}\\
R \cos(\phi)\\
R\sin(\phi)\\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

However, as the loop rotates with a fixed frequency after a quarter turn the orientation of the loop is now:
$$
\mathbf{l}_{RF:B}(R,\phi;t=\frac{\pi}{2\omega})= R \left(\begin{array}
\\R\cos(\phi)
\\0
\\R\sin(\phi)
\end{array}\right)
$$
As the loop describes a circle in the $x$-$z$-plane now.
The rotation matrix for the rotation of the loop around the x-axis is:
$$
\underline{\underline{\Theta}}_{RF:B}(t)=\left(\begin{array}\\1&0&0\\0& \cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t)  \\ 0 & \sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)\end{array}\right)
$$

In the frame of the magnetic field the loop is described by:

$$
\mathbf{l}_{RF:B}(R,\phi;t)=
\left(
\begin{array}
\\
R\cos(\phi)
\\
R\sin(\phi)\cos(\omega t)
\\
R\sin(\phi)\sin(\omega t)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The inverse matrix of $\underline{\underline{\Theta}}_{RF:B} $ describes how a magnetic field rotates about the loop in the reference frame of the loop:

$$
\underline{\underline{\Theta}}_{RF:Loop}=\left(
\begin{array}
\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos(\omega t) & \sin(\omega t)\\
0 & -\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The loop has the following parametrization in its reference frame:
$$
\mathbf{l}_{RF:Loop}(R,\phi)=\left(\begin{array}
\\
R\cos(\phi)\\
R\sin(\phi)\\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$

The magnetc field in the reference frame of the loop has the form

$$
\mathbf{B}_{RF:Loop}(t)=\underline{\underline{\Theta}}_{RF:Loop}(t)\mathbf{B}=\left(
\begin{array}
\\
0
\\
B\sin(\omega t)
\\
B\cos(\omega t)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

As the magnetic field is now time dependent and the loop is fixed, it is way easier to calculate the induced voltage.

And you can see that this voltage depends linearly on the rotation frequency of the loop.

Comment: That makes sense...But shouldn't this somehow follow mathematically from Maxwell's equations lest they're "wrong"/too general? I mean the differential form just says $\mathrm{rot}(E) = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$ without reference to any "loop". Then just applying Green's theorem gets you to the result in my question. Or is there something in Green's theorem about reference frames I don't understand?

Comment: It's the other way around. You start by the greens theorem on the line integral. As the enclosed area changes its orientation however, you have to account for this. This is done either by changing the reference frame or by trying to parametrize it appropriately. Only then, when this is done, you know your acting magnetic field. Of course, in the lab system B is fixed. As the loop changes its orientation however, the lab system is not quite fitting to find the voltage drop, the acting magnetic field is not constant - it was, if the loop didn't rotate and in this case your argument would work.

Comment: Would "rewriting" the Maxwell-Faraday equation as $\mathrm{rot}(E) = -\frac{\mathrm{d}B}{\mathrm{d}t}$, where the derivative is the material derivative with the velocity field being the velocity of the charges, be another way to incorporate/handle/think about the "reference frame complications"? Then, I could just blindly apply Green's theroem and the effect of the moving boundary would somehow automagically be included...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Maxwell's equations in the lab frame where $\vec B$ is static (they certainly should not be altered), and there is no *need* to change reference frames. One just needs to consider the magnetic component of the Lorentz force when calculating emf.